# python Ubuntu: too many open files [eventpoll]

Tags: python, ubuntu, memory-leaks, python-requests

Basically, it is a multi-threaded crawler program, which uses requests mainly. After running the program for a few hours, I keep getting the error "Too many open files".

By running: **lsof -p pid**, I saw a huge number of entries like below:

**python  75452 xxx 396u  a_inode    0,11        0    8121 [eventpoll]**

I cannot figure out what it is and how to trace back to the problem.
Previously, I tried to have it running in Windows and never seen this error.
Any idea how to continue investigating this issue? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the behavior in Windows really does differ from that of Ubuntu? Specficially, I think that Windows allows 2048 open files and that the standard ulimit on Ubuntu is 1024. I can imagine a crawler opening 1024 < x < 2048 files. That would produce reproduce your situation without meaning that there was a platform specific bug in your python code.

I don't run Windows, so I mght be wrong about the 2048. But Ubuntu's forums can help you get to 2048. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user

If you need >2048, then maybe there is a problem... I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that it is caused by Gevent. After replacing gevent with multi-thread, everything is just OK.

However, I still don't know what's wrong with gevent, which keeps opening new files(eventpoll).